# How to take the difference of two sums in two tables in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables to treat in a query for getting the product in hand.

```
ProdBiscuit 
+----+-----+-------+---------------+
| ID | QTY |StockID|    Name       |  
+----+-----+-------+---------------+
|  1 | 100 |   1   |  Bis Chocolat |
+----+-----+-------+---------------+
|  2 | 120 |   2   |  Bis Moutarde |
+----+-----+-------+---------------+
|  3 | 100 |   3   |  Bis Epice    | 
+----+-----+-------+---------------+

 StockData 
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
| ID | QTY |ProdID |Status|Type|
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  1 | 100 |   1   |   0  |  3 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  2 | 120 |   2   |   0  |  3 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  3 | 100 |   3   |   0  |  3 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----
|  4 | 200 |   1   |   0  |  4 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  5 | 200 |   2   |   0  |  4 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  6 | 48  |   1   |   0  |  2 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  7 |  96 |   2   |   4  |  3 |
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
|  8 | 200 |   1   |   4  |  4
+----+-----+-------+------+----+
```

ProdBiscuit ID is relational with StockData.ProdID

ProdBiscuit.StockId is relational with StockData.ID

StockData.Status = 0 => Entry in stock, > 0 =>Left the stock

Type means 2=>Macaron, 3=>Biscuit, 4=>Ganache
ProdID => ID of ProdBiscuit
StockID-> ID of StockData

With the method below I get this

```
+--------------+--------+---------+
|Name          |QTY PROD|QTY REST | 
+--------------+--------+---------+
|Bis Chocolat  |  100   |   100   |
+--------------+--------+---------+
|Bis Moutarde  |  120   |    24   |
+--------------+--------+---------+
|Bis Epice     |  100   |   100   |
+--------------+--------+---------+
```

Result is correct but the query seems to me to be incorrect.
Because in WHERE clause query search the rows where status > 0

However I get the correct result??

Here is my code :

```
 private void RefreshProd()
 {
     Int16 ProdQty;
     Int16 UsedQty;
     DateLst.Items.Clear();
     ProdLst.Items.Clear();
     QtyLst.Items.Clear();
     NomLst.Items.Clear();
     prodidLst.Items.Clear();
     using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
     {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tb.id, tb.qty,tb.nom, tb.proddate, IF(status > 0 AND tb.id = sd.prodid, sd.quantite, 0) AS rq FROM StockData AS sd, " + TableName + " AS tb WHERE sd.matcuisine = 3 AND sd.status > 0", conn))
        {
           conn.Open();
           try
           {
                 MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 while (r.Read())
                {
                   DateLst.Items.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(r["proddate"]).ToString("d"));
                   ProdQty = Convert.ToInt16(r["qty"]);
                   UsedQty = Convert.ToInt16(r["rq"]);
                   ProdLst.Items.Add(r["qty"]).ToString();
                   NomLst.Items.Add(r["nom"]);
                   prodidLst.Items.Add(r["id"]).ToString();
                   QtyLst.Items.Add((ProdQty-UsedQty).ToString());
                 }
           }
           catch (MySqlException e)
             {
                    MessageBox.Show("MYSQL ERROR--> " + e.ToString());
             }
        }
    }

}
```

I could not find the rub.

The thing that's astonishing me that the query seems to me to be faulty but gives a correct result.

In where clause I put a condition that the search must be "sd.status>0" but it seems to me it's fetching the status = ZERO conditions too.(Perhaps I am missing something technical in MYSQL WHERE clause)

How ever bu doing my premenade overthestackflow I learnt that UNION and JOIN is more powerfull then the method that I use.

Is there a more efficient way to write my query by JOIN oro UNION? I will appreciate your help. Because I couldn't find way to resolve it by this way.

Comment: Why do you have this two-way relationship? Presumably `stockid` is not an innate property of biscuits, and so has no business being in the product table! Oh, amd I still don't understand the difference between `product qty` and `stock qty`.

Comment: Yes product qty can be supressed. But for the production of macaron I need two composants chocolate and biscuit. Their quantities  are held in product (biscuit, chocolate).It's an int32 and in the product table I have the ingredients id nbrs and their quantities  So I don't want trigger each the stockdata during the production. In stock qty if status is zero it's an entry in stock 1= sold 2= gift 3= defective 4= used for the production of macaron. If you like I can send you what I wrote till now .

Comment: No thanks. The whole thing is too confusing. I'm afraid your schema  needs re-designing. 'Mustard Macaroons'? Who knew?

Comment: Perhaps but I am at the stage of discovering the c# and Mysql. This program I wrote in visual basic with I/O file . Now I am translating it in c# with mysql for learning both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query?

```
SELECT 
tb.id
, tb.qty
, tb.nom
, tb.proddate
, sd.quantity as rq
FROM 
  StockData AS sd
INNER JOIN " + TableName + " AS tb 
  On tb.id = sd.prodid
WHERE 
  sd.matcuisine = 3 
  AND sd.status > 0
```

Comment: I have to calculate the sum of qty used (in sd) and substract it form the qty of tb. But the qty(used) of sd is in 4-5 rows not in one row. Qty of tb is always in one row and the sd.status can never be null but must zero. It's on the definition of table . Thanks very much. The result I got only 2 rows of same products. I must have 3 rows. My code for the first entrey gives the correct result but in second entry gives the doubles.

Comment: EDIT: Btw, is there a logic reason why every value that you receive is placed in a list of types and not in 1 class list? To me this looks easier.

Comment: rq must be total of sd.quantity with condition (sd.status>0 AND sd.prodid = tb.id AND sd.matcuisine = 3) 
Explanation: 
sd.status >0 means it is used
sd.prodid is the ID of ProdBiscuit (tb) stored in Stockdata
matcuisine = 3 (search of the biscuit)

Comment: The syntax is not correct but must be in this logic
SELECT tb.id, tb.qty,tb.nom, tb.proddate FROM ProdBiscuit AS tb INNER JOIN StockData AS sd SELECT quantite, SUM(quantite)  AS rq ON (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status>0 AND sd.matcuisine =3)